# how to do serializing in c# when the input is array or list

Tags: c#, asp.net, serialization

I am sending out email using the webservices. I have send the xml to the webservice and it takes care of the rest.

Here the newuseremail I convert a list of email into string and pass it to sendemail method.

```
  string newuseremail= string.Join(",", lstnewuseremail.ToArray());
```

SO the xml out here is

```
<emailRequest>
  <toaddress>dasd@tg.com,adssd@tg.com</toaddress> 
  <subject>Welcome to ASF</subject> 
  <message /> 
  <username>sda@tg.com</username> 
  </emailRequest>
```

But I want the xml to be in this format

```
<emailRequest>
  <toaddress>dasd@tg.com</toaddress> 
  <toaddress>adssd@tg.com</toaddress>
  <subject>Welcome to ASF</subject> 
  <message /> 
  <username>sda@tg.com</username> 
  </emailRequest>


  public string SendEmail(string newuseremail, string subject, string message, string myemail)
        {
            string url = "dskjshdkh";     
            emailRequest test = new emailRequest();
            test.toaddress = newuseremail;
            test.subject = subject;
            test.message = message;
            test.username = myemail;       
            //serialize the inputs
            String XML;
            XML = SerializeAnObject(test);
            return HttpPost(XML, url);
        }
       //Serialize An Object
        public static string SerializeAnObject(object AnObject)
        {
            XmlSerializer Xml_Serializer = new XmlSerializer(AnObject.GetType());
            XmlSerializerNamespaces emptyNameSpace = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
            emptyNameSpace.Add("", "");
            XmlWriterSettings writerSettings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            writerSettings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
            StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
            using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stringWriter, writerSettings))
            {
                Xml_Serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, AnObject, emptyNameSpace);
            }
            return stringWriter.ToString();
        }   
    }
```

**UPDATE:**

Here I am seperating the array. But the xml is formed by ignoring all the toaddress, just the last toaddress is used in the xml

```
   public string SendEmail(string newuseremail, string subject, string message, string myemail)
    {
        string url = "http://localhost:8080/SurelyKnownMediaService/services/service/sendemail/";     
        emailRequest test = new emailRequest();
        string[] email = newuseremail.Split(',');
        foreach (string word in email)
        {
            test.toaddress = Convert.ToString(word);
        }    
        test.subject = subject;
        test.message = message;
        test.username = myemail;       
        //serialize the inputs
        String XML;
        XML = SerializeAnObject(test);
        return HttpPost(XML, url);
    }
```

Comment: What is wrong with your current code? What have you tried to do so far?

Comment: Take a look at this MSDN link and scroll down to the section where it says Serialize ArrayList http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2baksw0z%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

My proposal is to add another property of `List<string>` type to class you are serializing, implement `get` of the property which will parse your text `toaddress` and populate the list, mark existing `toaddress` with `XmlIgnore` attribute and mark new property with 
[XmlElement("toaddress")].

```
public class emailRequest
{
    [XmlElement]
    public List<string> toAddress { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: public List<string> toaddress; this is creating the email inside <toaddress><string>email</string></toaddress> how to create it without string in the middle. Can you give me the code to do it